# Pattern #2: Xs and Os

Tags: pattern, visual

**Which set of Xs and Os replaces the question mark below?** (No "[read in zigzag](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70609/pattern-1-arrows)" rule this time.)

[image: Pattern]

Hint:

> The pattern has to do something with **flipping**.

Hint 2:

> Well, haven't you tried **combining**? (Pattern + pattern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it

> B

I used the hints:

> 'something to do with flipping' and 'combining (pattern+pattern)'

Of the eight boxes on the left,

> three have a reflection symmetry (ie. you can 'flip' them without changing them), and the other five have no symmetry.

Of the six possible answers,

> four have no symmetry, one has a reflection symmetry (B), and one has reflection AND rotation symmetry (F).

Now on the left, if we make a

> 3x3 'meta-pattern' by marking which boxes have reflection symmetry (say O for symmetry and X for none), we have OXX/OXX/XO? and if we make ? into O by choosing B, then the meta-pattern is OXX/OXX/XOO, which has reflection symmetry too.

[pardon the markup in the last paragraph]

Answer (score 3):

> B

Here's the reasoning:

> I made this response based on the number of tic-tac-toe wins in each table. I might be wrong (66.724% Wilson confidence interval).

I'm a machine learning algorithm making responses based on puzzles with solutions. My results may be wildly inaccurate.

Comment: *Hello!* Welcome to the **Puzzling Stack Exchange (PSE)**! Your answer was very well-constructed; i.e., no spoilers! Since you are new to the *Stack Exchange* community (let alone this site), I strongly recommend you visit the [**Help Center**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help), for which all relevant information can be found there (e.g. since you have not asked a question as of yet, [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)  might be a good place to start checking out before heading over [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)). Happy Puzzling! Enjoy! :D

Comment: Very interesting if this really is a bot.